# Find objects at a point in google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, overlap

I am adding areas of interest in google maps using polygons and circles.
In each polygon and circle I'm adding an ID so I can get detailed information about that area if the user clicks on the polygon or circle.
There are cases that two areas overlap. By clicking the common area I'm able to get the ID for the object that is "above" but I have no way to get the ID of the object that lies "below". An example is given below.

[image]

Is there a way to get the IDs of overlapping objects?

The code that creates a polygon and a circle is given below.

```
function drawpolygonExersice(res, ExerciseID){
  var points = new Array();
  var ptn;

  for (var j=0;j<res.length/2;j++)
    {ptn = new google.maps.LatLng(res[2*j],res[2*j+1]);
      points.push(ptn);}
  var polygonExercise = new google.maps.Polygon({
    path: points,
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: 'red',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 1,
    fillColor: "red",
    fillOpacity: 0.20,
    ID: ExerciseID,  //look up ID
    map: map
  });
   google.maps.event.addListener(polygonExercise, 'click', function(event) {
     alert(this.ID);
   });
  exerciseAreas.push(polygonExercise);  
}

function drawcircleExersice(res, ExerciseID) {

  var circleExercise = new google.maps.Circle ({
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(res[0],res[1]),
      radius: res[2] * 1852, //Nautical miles to meters
      geodesic: true,
      strokeColor: 'red',      
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 1,
      fillColor:'red',
      fillOpacity: 0.20,
      ID: ExerciseID,  //look up ID
      map: map
    });

   google.maps.event.addListener(circleExercise, 'click', function(event) {
     alert(this.ID);
   });
   exerciseAreas.push(circleExercise);
}
```

Comment: how many of these shapes will be drawn on the map?

Comment: would have to check bounds of all the overlays that are visible

Comment: @Dr.Molle 10-40 shapes will be on the map, depends on search criteria.

Comment: I am not looking for a geometry solution, having in mind devices that are battery depended and don't like 'heavy' computations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The  only way I see is to iterate over all shapes and calculate(via geometry-library) if a shape contains the clicked latLng. It shouldn't be a problem with the expected amount of shapes.

For a circle use `.computeDistanceBetween(clickedLatLng,circle.getCenter())`, when the result is `<=circle.getRadius()` , the click has been on the circle.

For a polygon use `.containsLocation(clickedLatLng,polygon)`, when it returns `true` the click has been on the polygon.

Demo: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/qotg0o2x/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/qotg0o2x/)

Comment: Although your approach is correct (probably the only one) I failed to mention in my question that I wasn't looking for a geometry solution, having in mind devices that are battery depended and don't like 'heavy' computations.
If no other way exists I'll select your answer as correct.